# Log event ordering on different streams

Tags: python, stream, python-logging

Using Python I have created two logging Handlers: one for `sys.stdout` and one for `sys.stderr`. I've setup my code so that ERROR and "worse" (e.g. CRITICAL) go to the the stderr Handler, and WARNING and "better" go to the stdout Handler. My logging code:

`my_logger.info("info")`
`my_logger.warning("warning")`
`my_logger.error("error")`

On occasion, the ERROR will appear in the PyCharm terminal first even though it's executed last. Its timestamp is still chronologically later, however:

`2023-08-16T15:30:00.345678 error`
`2023-08-16T15:30:00.123456 info`
`2023-08-16T15:30:00.234567 warning`

Is this something to do with Python logging and Handlers, something with the PyCharm terminal, or just something more fundamental with output streams that I'm missing?

All behaves as expected when writing all messages just to stdout.